# Is there a command which lists installed applications based on whether they use GTK2 or GTK3?

Tags: gtk

I'm using Lubuntu 12.10 and I know of two ways to tell if a specific program uses GTK2 or GTK3:

- I can make changes in `~/.themes/theme_name/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`, for example, and see if a specific application's appearance is altered.
- I can run `ldd /usr/bin/specific_application | grep gtk`

Both these work on a **per-app** basis.

Is there a way to get a list of installed applications based on whether they use GTK2 or GTK3?

Comment: What might help you `echo 'n' | sudo apt-get remove libgtk-3-0`. It will show you a huge list (243 packages on my system) of that are depending on libgtk-3.

Comment: I modified that to `echo 'n' | apt-get remove -s libgtk-3-0` and it does the job, proposing the removal of 70 packages. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I looked for the counterpart to `-y` (that I use quite often`, but overlooked it searching for `-n` %-). But with -s, you no longer need to echo 'n' in the command

Comment: Newbie here. I use `-s` a lot with `apt-get`.

Comment: Did you check `apt-get remove` pertinence with `apt-cache rdepends`? On Arch Linux `pacman -Rs gtk3` lists five deps here, while `pacman -Sii` (list reverse dependancies) gives over two hundreds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at which packages the package manager knows to be dependent on this by using:

```
apt-get remove -s libgtk-3-0
```

The `-s` option makes sure this is a simulation so **nothing** is actually removed.

Answer (score 2):

```
aptitude search '~i ~D libgtk'
```

will list all your installed packages that directly depend on gtk.

---

The more specific

```
aptitude search '~i ~s gnome'
```

will list all your installed gnome packages.